# What hook is used to display the admin_bar on the front end?

Tags: hooks, admin-bar

Or, how is the admin_bar displayed at all? I'm looking to display a similarly styled menu, but for all users who visit.

Comment: Please clarify what a "dashboard" front end is to you.

Comment: The Dashboard menu on the front end is aka the admin_bar.

Comment: Then please rework your title and the tags to read "Admin Bar". Currently your question is filed under the wrong tag archive and targets the wrong audience.

Comment: Ok, I changed the question wording.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you are talking about the admin_bar which has many hooks. 
You can read more about

- [wp_before_admin_bar_render](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/wp_before_admin_bar_render)
- and wp_after_admin_bar_render

in codex and actually wp source.